# distinguishing between PJAX Events

Tags: javascript, jquery, pjax

My pjax is working fine, but I need to do different things on different `pjax` events. Here is my `pjax`:

```
//MainMenu
$(document).pjax('.menu li a', '.pjax_submenu', { fragment: '.pjax_submenu', timeout: 5000});

//SubMenu
$(document).pjax('.submenu li a', '.submenu', { fragment: '.submenu',  timeout: 5000 });
```

Basicly I have these two menues and want to do stuff on `pjax:start` and `pjax:end`. Unfortunatly these events are always called. e.g.:

```
$("body").on("pjax_event", ".pjax_submenu", function(e, category){
    $(document).on('pjax:start', function() {
        if(category === 1){
            $('.pjax_submenu').fadeOut(500);

        } else{
            $('.info').slideUp(500);

        }
    });
    $(document).on('pjax:end', function() {
        if(category === 1){
            $('.pjax_submenu').hide().fadeIn(500);
        } else{
            $('.info').hide().slideDown(500);
        }
    });
});

$("body").on("click", ".menu li a", function() {
    $(".pjax_submenu").trigger("pjax_event", 1);
});
$("body").on("click", ".submenu li a", function() {
    $(".pjax_submenu").trigger("pjax_event", 2);
});
```

It doesn't matter if I click on a menu or a sub menu link, the result is the execution of all `pjax` code.
Even if I do it like this:

```
$("body").on("click", ".menu li a", function() {
    $(document).on('pjax:start', function() { stuff }
    $(document).on('pjax:end', function() { stuff }
});
$("body").on("click", ".submenu li a", function() {
    $(document).on('pjax:start', function() { stuff }
    $(document).on('pjax:end', function() { stuff }
});
```

It still executes >both< and I can't seem to get my head around a method to distinguish the `pjax` events on different clicked items.

What I want to do is fade content on a main menu point and use slideUp/Down for the sub menu info boxes.

Tell me if you need any additional information, every help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to share my solution, it's not too pretty - but it works marvelous! Also it's the only solution I found...

You will need the pjax version that's readable!

Search pjax.js for "pjax:end". Add the paragrpah below:

```
fire('pjax:end', [xhr, options])

if(options.menu == 'main'){
    fire('pjax:main:end', [xhr, options])
}else if(options.menu == 'sub'){
    fire('pjax:sub:end', [xhr, options])
}
```

same for pjax:start!

You can then declare your pjax links with:

```
//MainMenu
$(document).pjax('.menu li a', '.pjax_submenu', {menu: 'main',fragment:'.pjax_submenu', timeout: 5000});
//SubMenu
$(document).pjax('.submenu li a', '.submenu', { menu: 'sub',fragment: '.submenu',  timeout: 5000 });
```

and voilà you have the separate events:

```
//... for Main Menu
$(document).on('pjax:main:start', function() {
    console.log('pjax:main:start');

});

$(document).on('pjax:main:end', function() {
    console.log('pjax:main:end');

});

//... for Sub Menu
$(document).on('pjax:sub:start', function() {
    console.log('pjax:sub:start');

});
$(document).on('pjax:sub:end', function() {
    console.log('pjax:sub:end');

    $('.info') .slideDown(500);
});
```

Hope this helps someone in the future!
Cheers!